# How to show PrimeFaces messages through p:messages without icon?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .addMessage("value", 
                 new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "you can't input this value", ""));
```

```
<p:messages for="value"
            showDetail="false"
            autoUpdate="true"
            display="text"/>
```

Hi everybody! It works great but I want to show only text message without  icon. How to resolve this? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0DM0.jpg)

[image]

I am using PrimeFaces 4.0 (where setting the `showIcon` attribute to false is not an option).

Comment: `<p:messages showIcon="false" .../>`

Comment: @Tiny is right, and if this did not work, there is always plain and simple css.

Comment: @Tiny: Please post that as answer rather than as comment.

Comment: Thanks, showIcon="false" don't work, but i just redefine css and it's works.
 .ui-messages-error-icon {
    display:none;
}

Comment: @LittleHobbit: Same applies on you. Please post that as an answer especially if that solved your problem in which case you should also [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Comment: `showIcon="false"` worked correctly for me (PrimeFaces 5.1) in all severity levels, `INFO`, `WARN`, `ERROR`, `FATAL`.

Comment: @Tiny I use PrimeFaces 4.0

Comment: @LittleHobbit: That is why you ALWAYS need to post version info

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially write something like this:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("value",   new FacesMessage("you can't input this value", ""));
```

Just remove this: `FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,`